# Fitting a variable using multiple equations

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I would like to find the best fit of two variables for a number of approximate equations, such as:

```
1x+2y+2=7.04
2x+y+4=7.98
1.5x+1.5y-2=2.53
1.8x+3y-1=6.77
```

That should come up with a result: `x = ~1`, `y = ~2` (exact value for whatever the best fit is).

I can't find any inspiration in either

- [CurveFittingAndApproximateFunctions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/CurveFittingAndApproximateFunctions.html) or
- [StatisticalModelAnalysis](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/StatisticalModelAnalysis.html)  .

I don't expect anyone to do it for me, but perhaps someone could push me in a correct direction?

Thanks in advance,
r.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is what you are after:

```
NMinimize[
 #.# &[Subtract @@@ {
    1 x + 2 y + 2 == 7.04,
    2 x + y + 4 == 7.98,
    1.5 x + 1.5 y - 2 == 2.53,
    1.8 x + 3 y - 1 == 6.77
    }],
 {x, y}]
```

> ```
> {0.00360363, {x -> 0.99076, y -> 2.00755}}
> ```

Comment: That's exactly what I've been looking for! Dzieki, Kuba!

Answer (score 2):

I tend to avoid black boxed solutions, whenever it's possible.
Here's how to build the least square solver from scratch:

> `LeastSquareSolve[A_, Ym_] :=     Inverse[Transpose[A].A].Transpose[A].Ym`

And to use it you just have to recast your equations in matrix form (a one-liner can be built for that, should you need it - there's one on Thomas Bahder's "Mathematica for Scientists and Engineers" wonderful book)

```
A = {{1, 2}, {2, 1}, {1.5, 1.5}, {1.8, 3}}
Ym = {{7.04 - 2}, {7.98 - 4}, {2.53 + 2}, {6.77 + 1}}
```

Now, its calling time:

```
LeastSquareSolve[A, Ym]
```

> ```
>     {0.99076, 2.00755}
> ```

BTW, there's even a builtin function that does just that: `PseudoInverse`, so that your solution can be found - once you have entered your `A` and `Ym` matrices, as:

```
PseudoInverse[A].Ym
```

> ```
>    {0.99076, 2.00755}
> ```

Comment: Better to use the built-in function `LeastSquares` than to explicitly form the pseudoinverse. Using the SVD method (which is what `PseudoInverse` does) is a lot better than finding it with an explicit `Inverse` as in your first example, but it can still be numerically unstable.

Comment: @OleksandrR., good point. I was not even aware there was a `LeastSquare` built-in function (MMA is growing larger and larger, the next manual will be a dictionary). The problem with what I call black-boxed approach is that one is tempted to overlook this sort of pitfalls, trusting the system to do the thinking. I did it with the black-box `Inverse` and `PseudoInverse`it seems :-)... But I guess that even `LeastSquares` and `NMinimize` are hiding pitfalls.