# Fitting a rotated ellipse to data points

Tags: computational-geometry

I have a bunch of x,y scatter data and I am trying to fit an ellipse through them. I understand that this question has been asked before and there are resources for this, e.g.:

[Fitting ellipse to 5 given points on the plane](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/60779/fitting-ellipse-to-5-given-points-on-the-plane)

[Fitting points to tilted, off-center ellipse](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51491/fitting-points-to-tilted-off-center-ellipse)

http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2001/Sep/msg00179.html

However, in my scenario, I need to add in an additional constraint. The ellipse may be rotated, but, it has to rotate about its pivot which is defined by the rightmost/lowest point. I illustrate this problem in the figure below, where the rotation of the 'best-fit' ellipse takes place about its pivot point (circled in red).

[image: Illustration]

In essence, this necessitates that the major semi-axis has to pass through that pivot point.

What would be the best possible way to incorporate this constraint in the ellipse fitting process?

Comment: Could you provide some test data, add a definition of your desired "best fit" (weight functions), and list any *Mathematica* code you have tried? Otherwise this seems more like a math problem, not a *Mathematica* issue.

Comment: LinearModelFit used in the second link allows for a Weights option. Simply give the pivot point a very large weight would do the trick, I guess.

Comment: Mmm..., no. That just forces the ellipse to go through that point, not the major axis.