# How to fit a surface to 3D data in Mathematica?

Tags: fitting

I have a set of data coordinates which is mostly compatible with an Ellipsoid:

```
{{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2}, ... , {xn,yn,zn}}
```

Now I want to find the best 3d volume that fits this data ( a 3D shape that passes closest to these data ).

I know how to use `Fit` command for one dimensional data but don't know how to do that in 3D.

Comment: simple, just apply one of these approaches in  3D : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51491/fitting-points-to-tilted-off-center-ellipse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not sure what the exact aim is and time does not permit refining some loose ends. Assuming reason to believe data is ellipsoid (as test data is):

Using test data from another answer:

```
data = Flatten[
   Table[{RandomReal[{1.9, 2.1}] Cos[n/100 2 Pi] Sin[m/100 Pi], 
     RandomReal[{0.9, 1.1}] Sin[n/100 2 Pi] Sin[m/100 Pi], 
     RandomReal[{0.9, 1.1}] Cos[m/100 Pi]}, {m, 100}, {n, 100}], 1];
```

Fit:

```
model = {#1^2, #2^2, #1, #2, #3, #1 #2, #1 #3, #2 #3, #3^2} & @@@ data;
lmf = LinearModelFit[
  model, {1, x2, y2, x, y, z, xy, xz, yz}, {x2, y2, x, y, z, xy, xz, 
   yz}]
fun[u_, v_, w_] := 
 lmf["BestFitParameters"].{1, u^2, v^2, u, v, w, u v, u w, v w}
```

Volume:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[fun[x, y, z] > z^2, {x, y, z}];
dreg = DiscretizeRegion[reg];
Volume[reg]
```

yields: 8.45783

See *original answer* for graphics and examples of model properties. Only difference data used.

**Original Answer (based on misunderstanding)**

`ConvexHullMesh` provides an enclosing convex volume:

```
ch = ConvexHullMesh[data]
```

[image]

Fitting:

```
chv = ch["VertexCoordinates"];
mod = {#1^2, #2^2, #1, #2, #3, #1 #2, #1 #3, #2 #3, #3^2} & @@@ chv;
lm = LinearModelFit[
  mod, {1, x2, y2, x, y, z, xy, xz, yz}, {x2, y2, x, y, z, xy, xz, 
   yz}]
f[u_, v_, w_] := 
 lm["BestFitParameters"].{1, u^2, v^2, u, v, w, u v, u w, v w}
```

The model is reasonable and (as how data generated implies) suggests dropping cross and translation terms (I won't do for time sake).

[image]

```
Show[ContourPlot3D[
  f[u, v, w] - w^2 == 0, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}, {w, -2, 2}, 
  Mesh -> False, ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.3]], 
 Graphics3D[Point[data]]]
```

[image]

The equation: 1.17889 + 0.00294153 x - 0.277082 x2 - 0.00261799 xy - 
 0.000551349 xz - 0.00163403 y - 1.01096 y2 - 0.00399276 yz + 
 0.0000264809 z=z^2.

Again, this could clearly be simplified but I do not have time to reduce/simplify model.

Volume of region can be determined in a number of ways:
, e.g. `Volume[ch]` yields: 9.95036

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[f[x, y, z] > z^2, {x, y, z}]
DiscretizeRegion[ir]
Volume[DiscretizeRegion[ir]]
```

yields: 9.91025.

This is larger than volume of ellipsoid (2,1,1) and is really fit of convex hull. This, again, is fitting ellipsoid by creating convex hull mesh from data points. The intent of the question may have been for more complex data sets in shape and convex hull may not be ideal.

Comment: I think you forgot the definition of `f`. Also, why not apply `LinearModelFit` directly to the data points rather than to the vertices of the convex hull?

Comment: @Rahul thank you 'cut and paste' error have amended now. I transformed the data to allow use of linear model and to deal with translated and rotated ellipsoids (not relevant in this case), i.e. general quadric surface and avoid non-linear model fit.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the error! Sorry my question was unclear. I understand the quadratic transformation of the data, what I want to know is why you are working with only the subset of the data that lies on the convex hull. If I construct `mod` using `data` instead of `chv` it works fine and I get a better estimate of the volume.

Comment: @Rahul i was not sure what the aim was but agree that there are better ways of trying to work out volume of data...this provides a, not so good, estimate by fitting convex hull...I hope to learn from much better answers than mine.

Comment: @Rahul...I should have looked more carefully at test data...it is only the 'shell' with noise so I should have used all the data! I stupidly thought it was points randomly distributed bounded by ellipse...will update when I get time! Yes use ALL the data...thanks

Comment: I can not find the Volume command. Is it because my Mathematica version is 9.0 ?

Comment: @Aug yes a version 10 functionality...sorry for not being explicit

Comment: Yeah, I upgraded my Mathematica and your technique works fine.   I am just wondering why not to use the simple Volume[ch] for volume calculation ? ( assuming we forget about the ellipse shape )

Answer (score 6):

This is not very *Mathematica* style, but it will do the job.

We start with a trial data set which is confined in an ellipsoid

```
data = 
 Flatten[
  Table[
   {RandomReal[{1.9, 2.1}] Cos[n/100 2 Pi] Sin[m/100 Pi], 
    RandomReal[{0.9, 1.1}] Sin[n/100 2 Pi] Sin[m/100 Pi],
    RandomReal[{0.9, 1.1}] Cos[m/100 Pi]}, 
   {m, 100}, {n, 100}], 1];

Graphics3D[Point[data]]
Mean[data]
```

[image]

> ```
> {0.000349362, -0.000145455, -0.00919064}
> ```

First we figure out the range of the data

```
{x1, x2} = {Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}
{y1, y2} = {Min[data[[All, 2]]], Max[data[[All, 2]]]}
{z1, z2} = {Min[data[[All, 3]]], Max[data[[All, 3]]]}
```

Then we select the upper and lower surface by choosing the `Max` and `Min` for a small `xy` area with side `d`

```
d = 0.05;
sdat = 
 Flatten[
  Table[
   dat1 = 
    Select[data,
     x - d/2 <=  #[[1]] < x + d/2 && y - d/2 <= #[[2]] < y + d/2 &];
  {x, y, Min[dat1[[All, 3]]], Max[dat1[[All, 3]]]},
  {x, x1, x2,d}, {y, y1, y2, d}], 1];

up = 
 Select[sdat[[All, {1, 2, 4}]], 0 <= #[[3]] <= z2 &];
dn = 
 Select[sdat[[All, {1, 2, 3}]], z1 <= #[[3]] < 0 &];

Graphics3D[
 {Red, Point[up], Blue, Point[dn], 
  PointSize[Small], Green,  Point[data]},
 Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Or use `ListSurfacePlot3D` for better vissualisation.

```
Show[
 ListSurfacePlot3D[up],
 ListSurfacePlot3D[dn],
 Graphics3D[{Blue, Point[data]}]
]
```

[image]

Since you have the surfaces you can do anything with them. you can use `Interpolation` if you need a function for the surfaces.

**Volume**

You can use `Interpolation`

```
gup = Interpolation[up];
vup = NIntegrate[gup[x, y], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}]

gdn = Interpolation[dn];
vdn = NIntegrate[gdn[x, y], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}]

Abs[vup] + Abs[vdn]
```

> 3.98669
>
> -4.03046
>
> 8.01715

The "-" sign comes due to the way we choose the limits. These are the volume of upper and lower part. Total volume is their sum - that's all.

The volume of an ellipsoid is $\frac43 \pi a b c$. If you roughly consider $a = 2$ and $b=c=1$, then it is 8.37758.

Not bad, right!

**Comment**

I made a small mistake earlier in defining `up` and `dn`. I corrected it now. As a result you can see the volume is closer to the actual result.

Comment: That looks great !  Is there any way to calculate its volume and surface also ?

Comment: Thanks @ShutaoTang for the edit. It looks much better.

Answer (score 2):

Here's sample data:

```
testdata = {{2, 0, 0}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, -1, 0}, {0, 0, 
    5}, {0, 0, -5}, {1, 1, 4}, {2, 4, -3}};
```

Here's the covariance matrix:

```
myCov = Covariance[testdata];
```

Here's the solution (z value) for a best-fit ellipse:

```
mysols = Solve[{x, y, z}.Transpose[myCov].myCov.{x, y, z} == 5, z]

{{z -> (17119 x + 51177 y - 
    8 Sqrt[89161135 - 67267296 x^2 - 131440176 x y - 96338312 y^2])/
   363923}, {z -> (
   17119 x + 51177 y + 
    8 Sqrt[89161135 - 67267296 x^2 - 131440176 x y - 96338312 y^2])/
   363923}}
```

Here's a plot of the solution ellipse:

```
myellipse = ParametricPlot3D[
  {{x, y, (
    17119 x + 51177 y - 
     8 Sqrt[89161135 - 67267296 x^2 - 131440176 x y - 96338312 y^2])/
    363923},
   {x, y, (
    17119 x + 51177 y + 
     8 Sqrt[89161135 - 67267296 x^2 - 131440176 x y - 96338312 y^2])/
    363923}}, 
  {x, -6, 6}, {y, -6, 6}, 
  BoxRatios -> {5, 1, 1},
  ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Fit.html) can be used for this purpose.

Here is some data in three dimensions:

```
data = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 2}, {1, 1, 0}, {1/2, 1/2, 1}};
```

Find the plane that best fits the data:

```
plane = Fit[data, {1, x, y}, {x, y}]
```

[image]

Show the plane with the data points:

```
Show[Plot3D[plane,  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}], 
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Map[Point, data]}]]
```

[image]

Find the quadratic that best fits the data:

```
 quad = Fit[data, {1, x, y, x^2, x y, y^2}, {x, y}]
```

[image]

The quadratic actually interpolates the data:

```
 Show[Plot3D[quad,  {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Opacity[.5], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}], 
Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.05], Map[Point, data]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this will work with an ellipse because an ellipse is not a single-valued function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that--I'm going to look into it more.