# Behaviour of RegionDistance with Ellipse?

Tags: fitting, regions

The data is:

```
data = {{13, 60}, {36, 35}, {70, 29}, {106, 41}, {118, 72}, {94, 
    94}, {49, 99}, {24, 85}};
```

When I try to find a fit circle,So my method is work well:

```
circle = Circle[{x, y}, r];
fitcir = RegionDistance[circle, #] & /@ data // Total // 
  ArgMin[# // N, {x, y, r}] &

(*{68.8023, 63.6189, 43.5349}*)
```

The effect like:

[image]

But the same method for a ellipse will be failure:

```
ellipse = Circle[{x, y}, {a, b}];
RegionDistance[ellipse , #] & /@ data // Total // 
 ArgMin[# // N, {x, y, a, b}] &
```

The code will collapse my `Mathematica`,and furthermore,

```
RegionDistance[ellipse,{13, 60}]
```

will be failure to run.

But we can see

```
In[36]:= ellipse // RegionQ
Out[36]= True
```

So it is a bug for RegionDistance?

Comment: Please wait for confirmation from others who observe this behaviour before adding the "bugs" tag

Comment: @blochwave Oh,I get it.thanks for your prompt.

Comment: with the above fix under v10.1 it just runs for a long time.  I think that's just a consequence of the complexity of the calculation of an analytic distance between a point and a general ellipse. (ie. not a bug IMO ).

Comment: @george2079 I'm very sorry to make this typo,and I have corrected it just.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the most significant speedup can be achieved using machine precision explicitly in the calculation of the distances, rather than arbitrary precision numbers. This is the reason I apply `N` to `data` before calculating the distances below.

---

A tweak is possible in the Nelder-Mead minimization algorithm used by `NMinimize` (I tested other algorithms and they all seemed slower). It seems effective to **provide a reasonable initial guess** of the ellipse's parameters. An acceptable estimate can be obtained using the bivariate mean and standard deviation of `data`. The center of the ellipse is approximated by the `Mean` of `data`; the length of the semiaxes is estimated using the standard deviation of `data`. This of course is inaccurate, but it is good enough to provide a reasonable starting point for the minimizer.

It is also interesting to the note that the **post-processing steps** (local minimization) taken after the Nelder-Mead algorithm seem *crucial* to obtaining a good fit in these cases. It is easy to convince oneself of this by turning those off using `"PostProcess" -> False` as a further option to the Nelder-Mead algorithm. The much slower post-processing is responsible for the slow-down of the counters observed during optimization, and for the final cleanup of the obtained ellipse that appears as a sudden jump in the animated series of intermediate steps shown at the very bottom of this answer.

---

I then instrumented the minimization code to provide step (`s`) and evaluation (`e`) counters updated dynamically during the calculation, so one knows what is going on, and by harvesting the intermediate results using `Sow` and `Reap`. The latter was just for fun, to see what stages the optimization traversed.

---

Here are the code and results of the minimization:

```
data = {{13, 60}, {36, 35}, {70, 29}, {106, 41}, {118, 72}, {94, 94}, {49, 99}, {24, 85}};

s = 0; e = 0;
Row[{"Evaluation: ", Dynamic[e], ", Steps: ", Dynamic[s]}]

(* Notice application of N to data before calculating distances *)
totdist = Total[RegionDistance[Circle[{x, y}, {a, b}], #] & /@ N[data]];

{{minval, minrules}, {{evalist}, {steplist}}} =
  Reap[
    NMinimize[
      {totdist, a > 0, b > 0},
      {a, b, x, y},
      EvaluationMonitor :> (e++; Sow[{a, b, x, y}, eval]),
      StepMonitor :> (s++; Sow[{a, b, x, y}, step]),
      MaxIterations -> 150,
      Method -> {
         "NelderMead",
         "InitialPoints" -> {Flatten@{StandardDeviation[data], Mean[data]}}
      }
    ],
    {eval, step}
  ];

minrules

Graphics[{
  Red, Circle[{x, y}, {a, b}] /. minrules,
  Black, PointSize[0.02], Point@data, AspectRatio -> 1
}]
```

[image: running counter]

```
(* Out: {a -> 53.3652, b -> 35.1669, x -> 66.0047, y -> 64.0812} *)
```

[image: fitted ellipse]

---

One can take a closer look at the **intermediate steps** in the optimization process that were saved in `steplist`. Alternatively, `evalist` can be substituted for `steplist` if one is interested in each evaluation of the function to be minimized.

```
ListAnimate[
 Graphics[{
     Red, Circle[{#3, #4}, {#1, #2}],
     Black, PointSize[0.02], Point[data]
    },
    PlotRange -> 
        Transpose @ Through[{Subtract, Plus}[Mean[data], 3 StandardDeviation[data]]],
    Axes -> True
 ] & @@@ steplist,
 AnimationRepetitions -> 1
]
```

[image: animation of steps]

---

Finally, here is some code to generate a set of "noisier" points from an axis-aligned ellipse:

```
With[
  {xc = 2, yc = 5, a = 30, b = 22},
  data = (# + RandomReal[{-1, 1}] &) /@
    FindInstance[(x - xc)^2/a^2 + (y - yc)^2/b^2 == 1, {x, y}, Reals, 15][[All, All, 2]]
];
```

... and here is an example of a best-fit ellipse obtained from such points. This required more iterations (`MaxIterations` was set to 600), but still only 14.3 s overall:

[image: noisier ellipse]

Comment: Very nice answer!!

Answer (score 3):

this does not directly address the issue, but this works using `RegionDistance` in a purely numeric way:

```
data = {{13, 60}, {36, 35}, {70, 29}, {106, 41}, {118, 72}, {94, 
   94}, {49, 99}, {24, 85}}; 
d[{x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ}, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, data_] := 
 RegionDistance[Circle[{x, y}, {Abs[a], Abs[b]}], #] & /@ data // 
   Total // N

f=NMinimize[d[{x, y}, a, b, data], {x, y, a, b}]
```

> {2.35102, {x -> 65.9529, y -> 64.0925, a -> 53.3151, b -> 35.1669}}

```
  Show[{RegionPlot[ Circle[{x, y}, {Abs[a], Abs[b]}] /. Last@f ], 
         ListPlot[data]}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
           PlotRange -> {{0, 120}, {0, 120}}]
```

[image]

BTW This is really slow.. see here for some better approaches:
[Fitting points to tilted, off-center ellipse](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51491/2079)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.Actually I can use FindFit to do it,learning from a friend.But I don't like the FindFit because of its initial value hard to find.And the new function of ` Geometry Computation` is very convenience I thank.your `purely numeric way` is work.As you say,It's very slow.But all the same `RegionDistance[Circle[{x, y}, {Abs[a], Abs[b]}], {13, 60}]` will failure to run.Can you give any opinion?

Comment: @yode will the symbolic `RegionDistance` really fail with an error, or will it just run for a very long time?

Comment: @MarcoB Will collapse my Mthematica in my computer.It is running normally in your??

Comment: @yode Do you do understand you are requesting an analytic expression for nearest distance to an arbitrary ellipse? This problem is intractable, or if a solution can be produced it will be a uselessly cumbersome conditional expression involving roots of transcendental expressions.

Comment: @george2079 I'm sorry for I don't know how complicated it is actually.I don't know too many problem that I can  figure out it with `Mathematica`.And I think It should be a matter of concern by `Wolfram Research`.A good tool should help even a common people,which is a `Mathematica`'s pursuit,isn't it?BTW even though kind you and @MarcoB  give some solution for this problem so that I can solve it now,I'm still not satisfied with the behavior of `RegionDistance` in such case.

Comment: @yode This is not really a shortcoming of `RegionDistance`: there is no simple and general expression for the distance of a point from an arbitrary ellipse. Take a look at this file ([Distance from a Point to an Ellipse, an Ellipsoid, or a Hyperellipsoid](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/DistancePointEllipseEllipsoid.pdf)).

Comment: @MarcoB Oh,thanks for your PDF to help me learn a lot.