# How to use ContourPlot to omit part of a contour and colour two remaining parts differently from each other?

Tags: plotting

I'm using Mathematica v7, in which the following code plots an ellipse ([many thanks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180734/how-to-use-mathematica-to-plot-an-ellipse-given-foci-and-semimajor-axis) to @Kirma ):

```
With[{foci = {{3, 2}, {5, 1}},
  semimajoraxis = 1.7},
 Show[
  ContourPlot[
   Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, p], {p, foci}] == 2 semimajoraxis, 
   Evaluate[
    Sequence @@ 
     MapThread[{#1, #2 - semimajoraxis, #2 + semimajoraxis} &, {{x, 
        y}, Mean[foci]}]], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   ContourStyle -> {Blue}]]]
```

How can I use `ContourPlot` to omit one part of this contour and colour a second part red and a third part blue?

For example, how can I omit the part for which $x+y-4<0$ and, of what remains, colour the part for which $x+2y-8>0$ red and the other part blue?

Comment: for the first part of your question, you can use `RegionFunction -> (# + #2 - 3.5< 0 &)` (but this does not remove any part of the contour).

Comment: Thanks for this. I made a mistake with the linear inequalities, which I have now corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html) to remove some parts of the graphics. To color different portions of the remaining part, you can produce two different plots using [`ConditionalExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConditionalExpression.html) in the first argument. The two plots correspond to whether or not the condition `#[[1]] + 2 #[[2]] - 5 >= 0` is satisfied:

```
sel = #[[1]] + 2 #[[2]] - 5 >= 0 &;
regf = (# + #2 - 6 < 0 &);
With[{foci = {{3, 2}, {5, 1}}, semimajoraxis = 1.7}, 
 Show[ContourPlot[ConditionalExpression[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, p], {p, foci}], 
   #[{x, y}]] == 2 semimajoraxis, 
  Evaluate[Sequence @@ MapThread[{#1, #2 - semimajoraxis, #2 + semimajoraxis} &, 
    {{x, y}, Mean[foci]}]], AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  ContourStyle -> Directive[#2, Thick], 
  RegionFunction -> regf] & @@@ {{sel, Red}, {Not[sel@#] &, Blue}}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can post-process `ContourPlot` output to (1) extract contour line coordinates, (2) create a `BSplineFunction` from extracted coordinates, and (3) use it with `ParametricPlot` with a combination of `Mesh*` options and `RegionFunction`:

```
cp = With[{foci = {{3, 2}, {5, 1}}, semimajoraxis = 1.7}, 
   ContourPlot[Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, p], {p, foci}] == 2 semimajoraxis, 
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ MapThread[{#1, #2 - semimajoraxis, #2 + semimajoraxis} &, 
      {{x, y}, Mean[foci]}]], 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ContourStyle -> Directive[Blue, Thick]]];

meshf = # + 2 #2 - 5 &;
bsF = BSplineFunction[Join @@ Cases[Normal@cp, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]];
ParametricPlot[bsF[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], 
 MeshFunctions -> {meshf}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> PointSize[0], 
 MeshShading -> Thread[Directive[{Blue, Red}, Thick]], Frame -> True, 
 RegionFunction -> regf]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses only a single [`ContourPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot) (I modified the predicates to be the same as kglr's):

```
s[foci_] := Sum[EuclideanDistance[{x,y},p], {p, foci}]

With[{foci = {{3, 2}, {5, 1}}, semimajoraxis = 1.7},
    ContourPlot[
        {
        ConditionalExpression[s[foci], x + 2 y - 5 >= 0] == 2 semimajoraxis,
        ConditionalExpression[s[foci], x + 2 y - 5 < 0] == 2 semimajoraxis
        },
        Evaluate[
            Sequence @@ MapThread[
                {#1, #2 - semimajoraxis, #2 + semimajoraxis} &,
                {{x, y}, Mean[foci]}
            ]
        ],
        RegionFunction -> Function[{x,y}, x+ y - 6<0],
        ContourStyle -> {Red, Blue}
    ]
]
```

[image]