# fitting an ellipse to a data

Tags: fitting

I want to fit an ellipse model to a data. This sample data I extracted from a simple parametric plot of `2 Sin[t], Cos[t]`(Let's say, I don't know that) and I want to fit my model of an ellipse to this data. This is what I have tried:

Sample data:

```
data = Flatten[ Cases[ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], 2 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}], Line[data_] :> data, Infinity], 1];
```

Model:

```
x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1
f[x_]:=Sqrt[(1 - x^2/a^2) b^2];
```

and,

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data,f[x], {a,b}, x]
```

It throws me complex infinity error and I am not able to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You did not post your data so it is difficult to answer your question, but you should look at [SingularValueDecomposition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingularValueDecomposition.html) and at this answer [51549](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51549/61809).

Comment: @TimLaska Hi, data can be obtained from the first code `data`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that.

Comment: The function form indicated will only be correct for the upper half of the ellipse. If you use the implicit form then there is no issue with negative `y` values.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau yes, daniel it's for the positive half as I haven't put the other solution of y. However, Still throws me complexinfinity error without giving a fit.

Comment: You could use `breg = BoundingRegion[data, "FastEllipse"]` and get a quick and very close approximation to the ellipse which gives `Ellipsoid[{-0.00227863, 0.00734437}, {{1.00538, 0.0000434228}, {0.0000434228, 4.07901}}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the model is of the form f(x,y) = 1, arrange the data as {{x,y,1} . . } for the fit:

```
(* make some data *)
(* the data is of the form { {x,y,1}, . . . } *)

eq = x^2/4 + y^2/9 == 1;

y[xx_] := y /. Solve[eq /. x -> xx, y]

points = Union[
   Flatten[Table[{x, y[x]}, {x, 
       Range[-2, 2, .1]}] /. {x_, {y1_, y2_}} -> {{x, y1, 1}, {x, y2, 
        1}}, 1]];

(* plot the data *)
ListPlot[points[[All, {1, 2}]]]

(* the general model *)

model = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2;

(* fit the data *)

fit = NonlinearModelFit[points, model, {a, b}, {x, y}];

fit["BestFitParameters"]

(* {a\[Rule]2.`,b\[Rule]2.999999999953799`} *)
```

Comment: it works for the sample file but If I am to do it for my data(which isn't too big) it gives me a fitting parameter of a circle that is not consistent with the data plot. If you have time could you please have a look at it, here is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18SPat0tEhQkkKQi_VggOANe4ZUNpw5UY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Rupesh Your data has exponents of -29 and -30.  If you multiply the $x$ and $y$ values by 10^30, the code above works just fine.

Comment: @David Keith, thanks man you are awesome, worked like a charm

Comment: @JimB Thanks Jim, you are a life saver.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [`SingularValueDecomposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SingularValueDecomposition.html) approach following @Danial Lichtblau's answer to [51549](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51549/61809).

```
mean = Mean[data];
newpts = Map[# - mean &, data];
{uu, ww, vv} = SingularValueDecomposition[newpts, 2];
ListPlot[uu, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
rsqr = Mean[Map[#.# &, uu]];
{nx, ny} = Inverse[vv.ww].({x, y} - mean);
expr = Expand[nx^2 + ny^2] == rsqr;
expr = MultiplySides[expr, 1/expr[[2]]] // Expand
reg = ImplicitRegion[expr[[1]] <= expr[[2]] 1.1, {x, y}];
ContourPlot[Evaluate@expr, {x, y} \[Element] reg, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Medium], Point[data]}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: SVD Images]

Comment: it's a nice approach and I appreciate you spending time on this, but it still doesn't fit to my main [data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18SPat0tEhQkkKQi_VggOANe4ZUNpw5UY/view). The solution given by David after using Jim's suggestion works.

Comment: @Rupesh I could not get your data file to import cleanly.  If you edit your post to show how to import your file, then I could take a look.  For example, you could `Compress[data]` and upload to [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/). Then, you can regenerate the data by `data2 = Uncompress[
  Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/GmDR0nRH", 
   "String"]]; data == data2 (* True *)` as I did for your original dataset.

Comment: I usually import these dat files I generate as TSV. Please try this. It should work.`Import["data.dat",  "TSV"] /. s_String :> ToExpression[s]`. I will look option for Pastebin too, just woke up