# Fitting C-shaped points with right-pointing parabola, ellipse, circle or other

Tags: fitting, geometry

I was trying to fit the following points:

```
points = {{28.8729, 57.1427}, {28.8752, 57.1733}, {28.8784, 57.2011}, 
 {28.8815, 57.2283}, {28.8816, 57.1297}, {28.8858, 57.1148}, {28.8867, 
  57.2515}, {28.8859, 57.208}, {28.8926, 57.1102}, {28.894, 
  57.2801}, {28.8934, 57.2432}, {28.8991, 57.0976}, {28.9076, 
  57.1042}, {28.9108, 57.3016}, {28.9143, 57.1039}, {28.9135, 
  57.0916}, {28.9191, 57.0501}, {28.9193, 57.3147}, {28.9256, 
  57.0781}, {28.9276, 57.0447}, {28.9356, 57.0395}, {28.9392, 
  57.3384}, {28.9433, 57.0234}, {28.9508, 57.0259}, {28.9582, 
  57.3489}, {28.9621, 57.0147}, {28.9736, 57.0092}, {28.9771, 
  57.3778}, {28.9791, 56.9927}, {28.9913, 56.9889}, {28.9971, 
  57.4146}, {28.9994, 56.9892}, {29.0084, 56.9813}, {29.0108, 
  57.4304}, {29.0166, 56.9784}, {29.0233, 56.9603}, {29.0247, 
  56.9741}, {29.0341, 56.9741}, {29.0425, 56.98}, {29.0495, 
  56.9795}, {29.0581, 56.9782}, {29.0678, 56.9751}, {29.0751, 
  56.9879}, {29.0821, 57.0118}, {29.0915, 57.0134}, {29.1001, 
  57.0207}, {29.1071, 57.0237}, {29.1065, 57.009}};
ListPlot[points]
```

[image]

The objective is to reach a function that fits the points, something similar to this:
[image]

In my understanding, this looks like a [right-pointing parabola](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/suny-osalgebratrig/chapter/the-parabola/):

[image]

So I tried this function, but it didn't work (the fit was inaccurate):

```
curveFit = Plot[57.01032231556321` + 
    4.524767722795246` *(-29.0814390274144`+x)^2,
   {x,28,29.33}, PlotStyle -> Orange]; 
Show[points, curveFit]
```

[image]

So I decided to try to fit an ellipse or circle instead, but I don't know how to do it in an automated way (maybe like a Monte Carlo simulation). So I drew an ellipse on top of the points:

```
h=29.01(*x-coordinate of the center*);
k=57.175(*y-coordinate of the center*);
a=0.13(*radius along the x-axis*);
b=0.2(*radius along the y-axis*);
ellipse=ParametricPlot[{h+a Cos[t], k+b Sin[t]},
  {t,0,2 Pi}, PlotRange->All, AxesLabel->{"x","y"},
  AxesOrigin -> {h-a, k-b}, PlotStyle->Orange]
    
Show[ellipse, points]
```

[image]

I hope anyone can guide me on the right way to proceed.

Comment: Without `points`, I doubt anyone can verify their candidate method.

Comment: Can you make the data available and mention how it was generated?  For example, are these points sequential in time?  In other words are there really 3 variables (x, y, and time)?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2980791.

Comment: Can you supply more specifics about your objective in "fitting" ?  Here are some examples:  (1) If the objective is to provide a curve that is an approximation of the data with a formula (parabola, ellipse, or something else), how close must that approximation be?  (2) If the objective is to predict future points, what is the mechanism for generating the current data and future data?  (3) If the objective is "I'll know it when I see it", then know that we can't read your mind (based on your statement: "But still, these two approaches are not the 'best fit', it just a better guess.").

Answer (score 6):

Here is approach based on this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51501/1997)

Data provided:

```
data = {{28.8729, 57.1427}, {28.8752, 57.1733}, {28.8784, 
    57.2011}, {28.8815, 57.2283}, {28.8816, 57.1297}, {28.8858, 
    57.1148}, {28.8867, 57.2515}, {28.8859, 57.208}, {28.8926, 
    57.1102}, {28.894, 57.2801}, {28.8934, 57.2432}, {28.8991, 
    57.0976}, {28.9076, 57.1042}, {28.9108, 57.3016}, {28.9143, 
    57.1039}, {28.9135, 57.0916}, {28.9191, 57.0501}, {28.9193, 
    57.3147}, {28.9256, 57.0781}, {28.9276, 57.0447}, {28.9356, 
    57.0395}, {28.9392, 57.3384}, {28.9433, 57.0234}, {28.9508, 
    57.0259}, {28.9582, 57.3489}, {28.9621, 57.0147}, {28.9736, 
    57.0092}, {28.9771, 57.3778}, {28.9791, 56.9927}, {28.9913, 
    56.9889}, {28.9971, 57.4146}, {28.9994, 56.9892}, {29.0084, 
    56.9813}, {29.0108, 57.4304}, {29.0166, 56.9784}, {29.0233, 
    56.9603}, {29.0247, 56.9741}, {29.0341, 56.9741}, {29.0425, 
    56.98}, {29.0495, 56.9795}, {29.0581, 56.9782}, {29.0678, 
    56.9751}, {29.0751, 56.9879}, {29.0821, 57.0118}, {29.0915, 
    57.0134}, {29.1001, 57.0207}, {29.1071, 57.0237}, {29.1065, 
    57.009}};
```

Fitting ellipse:

```
ref = {#1^2, #1, #2, 2 #1 #2, #2^2} & @@@ data;
ell = LinearModelFit[ref, {1, a, b, c, d}, {a, b, c, d}]
ellipse[x_, y_] := 
 ell["BestFitParameters"] . {1, x^2, x, y, 2 x y} - y^2
ContourPlot[ellipse[x, y] == 0, {x, 28.5, 29.5}, {y, 56.9, 57.6}, 
 Epilog -> Point[data]]
```

[image]

The equation for ellipse:
$1.87924 x^2-0.137714 x y-101.268 x+y^2-110.396 y+4627.53=0$

Answer (score 3):

If the objective is to draw a relatively smooth curve through the points, then finding a "parametric" equation that predicts both the $X$ and $Y$ coordinate from a single predictor might be considered.

```
(* Divide the data into two parts *)
data1 = Select[data, #[[2]] > 57.15 &];
data2 = Select[data, #[[2]] <= 57.15 &];
ListPlot[{data1, data2}]
```

[image: Data divided into two parts]

```
(* Now sort each part and join back together *)
data1 = Sort[data1, #1[[1]] > #2[[1]] &];
data2 = Sort[data2, #1[[1]] < #2[[1]] &];
data0 = Join[data1, data2];
ListPlot[data0, Joined -> True]
```

[image: Data joined in a specified order]

```
(* Fit both the x and y coordinates in "time" order *)
n = Length[data0];
lmx = LinearModelFit[data0[[All, 1]], {x, x^2, x^3, x^4}, x]
lmy = LinearModelFit[data0[[All, 2]], {y, y^2}, y]
f[t_] := {lmx[t], lmy[t]}
ListPlot[{data0, Table[f[t], {t, 1, n, 0.1}]}, 
 Joined -> {False, True}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Data and fit]

Now you have a function `f[t]` that will approximate the points where the predicted coordinates are found with a value of `t` from 1 to 48 (with 48 being the number of data points).

```
f[t]
(* {29.0452 - 0.028983 t + 0.00160732 t^2 - 0.0000303339 t^3 + 2.09131*10^-7 t^4,
    57.4545 - 0.024639 t + 0.000322699 t^2} *)
```

If the objective is to predict future data points, then describing the data generation process for the original and future data is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

FYI, the reason your fit was "inaccurate" is that your data is not a function of x. Switch the x and y points and refit. You'll get something closer, but the data is also not a function of y.

```
rpoints = Transpose[{points[[All, 2]], points[[All, 1]]}]; 
curve = Fit[rpoints, {y^2, y, 1}, y]; 
Show[ListPlot[points], 
 ParametricPlot[{curve, y}, {y, 56, 58}, PlotStyle -> Orange]]
```