# How can I fit a parabola to 2D data points?

Tags: fitting

I am looking for good Mathematica code to fit a parabola to 2D data, such as this:

```
data= {{15.4,59.1},{12.8,52.6},{5.8,34.9},{8.1,41.2},{9.7,45.0},{17.1,62.8},{25.7,82.5},{9.9,46.0},{6.4,36.9},{29.1,89.8},{60.0,42.0},{35.8,19.9},{27.0,12.4},{0.5,-0.8},{43.8,27.0},{25.7,11.5},{23.6,9.7},{62.9,44.7},{41.6,25.0},{14.0,3.03},{-1.6,5.3},{-1.4,10.2}};
ListPlot[data,PlotRange->{{-5,70},{-8,100}},Frame->True,Axes->False]
```

[image: Plot of data]

Based on a solution from cvgmt to [How to fit an ellipse to 2D data points?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288656/how-to-fit-an-ellipse-to-2d-data-points), we can do the following:

```
dataNLM=PadRight[#,3,1]&/@data;
nlm=NonlinearModelFit[dataNLM, a*x^2 + Sqrt[4*a*c]*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y, {a,c,d,e},{x,y}];
fit=nlm["BestFit"]
(* 0.154936*x-0.0154952*x^2+0.152321*y+0.0215755*x*y-0.00751045*y^2 *)
```

However, a plot of that curve and the data show that the fit doesn't look so good.

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[fit==1],{x,-5,70},{y,-8,100},Prolog->{AbsolutePointSize@5,Red,Point@data}]
```

[image: plot fit and data]

I suspect we can do better. There may be a better algorithm for this problem [here](https://cococubed.com/code_pages/conic.shtml). However, I am not proficient in the language used there. What could be some Mathematica code that does a very good job of fitting a parabola to the data above?

**UPDATE**

I used Manipulate to plot a parabola as I manually changed the coefficients. The best I found with that approach is this:

```
With[{a=-0.01664,c=-0.00778,d=0.1672,e=0.1315, f=0.0 },
  parabola = (a*x^2 + Sqrt[4 a c] x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f==0)
]
```

Notice that perfectly meets the condition for a parabola (b^2==4 a c). Then I use the above values for (a,c,d,e,f) for the search interval in NMinimize.

```
With[{sum=Expand@Total[((a*#1^2+b*#1*#2+b^2/(4 a)*#2^2+d*#1+e*#2+f)&@@@data)^2]},
  obj=Compile[{{a,_Real},{b,_Real},{d,_Real},{e,_Real},{f,_Real}},sum]
];
soln=NMinimize[{obj[a,b,d,e,f],0.00019<a^2},
  {{a,-0.018,-0.014},{b,0.02,0.024},{d,0.014,0.018},{e,0.11,0.15},{f,-0.001,0.001}}
];
fit=Function@Evaluate[a #1^2+b*#1*#2+b^2/(4 a)*#2^2+d*#1+e*#2+f/.Last@soln];
fit[x,y]
(* 0.010727+0.0336946 x-0.00339137 x^2+0.0278003 y+0.00465599 x y-0.00159805 y^2 *)
```

Notice (sum) above also forces the coefficients to meet the condition for a parabola. This might be close to the best fitting parabola. A plot of the above parabola and the data is below. If only I could make this automated, robust and efficient.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps tweak the `Weights` option?

Comment: Instead of fiddling with discriminants, why not directly plug in an actual parabola's implicit equation? `params = FindArgMin[{Norm[Function[{x, y}, (a x + b y)^2 + d x + e y + f] @@@ data], a^2 + b^2 == 1}, {a, b, d, e, f}]; eqn = (a x + b y)^2 + d x + e y + f /. Thread[{a, b, d, e, f} -> params]`

Comment: @Ted Ersek: Are you sure the `data` represents a parabola? Wasn't the `data` prepared by some random conic section equation that happened to be a hyperbola instead of parabola?

Comment: @J. M.'s lack of A.I.: Because then your code produces image similar to OP's one, such that data at the tip of parabola are quite off it. But I think it is because the data resembles more hyperbola then a parabola.

Comment: @azerbajdzan, yes, I would expect problems like that when you're forcing a particular conic fit instead of allowing any conic with no regard for the discriminant. (Not unlike when not all points will necessarily fall on a fitted line.)

Comment: @azerbajdzan: The data was created by adding a small amount of noise to samples of a hyperbola. However, I expect the best fitting parabola (in the least squares sense) would have the deviation from the curve spread across all the samples.

Answer (score 12):

```
$Version

(* "13.3.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 24, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

data = {{15.4, 59.1}, {12.8, 52.6}, {5.8, 34.9}, {8.1, 41.2}, {9.7, 
     45.0}, {17.1, 62.8}, {25.7, 82.5}, {9.9, 46.0}, {6.4, 
     36.9}, {29.1, 89.8}, {60.0, 42.0}, {35.8, 19.9}, {27.0, 
     12.4}, {0.5, -0.8}, {43.8, 27.0}, {25.7, 11.5}, {23.6, 
     9.7}, {62.9, 44.7}, {41.6, 25.0}, {14.0, 3.03}, {-1.6, 
     5.3}, {-1.4, 10.2}} // Rationalize;

dataNLM = PadRight[#, 3, 0] & /@ data;

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[dataNLM,
   {a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f,
    b^2 - 4*a*c == 0}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, {x, y},
   WorkingPrecision -> 15];

fit = nlm["BestFit"]

(* 0.0487531265441815 + 0.125368274231446 x - 0.0157932902455688 x^2 + 
 0.126417728935374 y + 0.0227628852631324 x y - 0.00757889272043125 y^2 *)

ContourPlot[Evaluate[fit == 0], {x, -5, 70}, {y, -8, 100}, 
 Prolog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, Point@data}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** To set  `f == 1`

Divide all of the coefficients by `f`

```
coef2 = CoefficientList[fit, {x, y}]/
   (fit /. {x -> 0, y -> 0});
```

Construct a parabola from the modified coefficients

```
fit2 = Fold[FromDigits[Reverse[#1], #2] &, coef2, {x, y}] // Simplify

1.00000000000000 - 0.323944152202351 x^2 + 
 x (2.57149198662846 + 0.466901035413677 y) + 2.59301788205953 y - 
 0.155454496104225 y^2
```

Plotting,

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[fit2 == 0], {x, -5, 70}, {y, -8, 100}, 
 Prolog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, Point@data}]
```

[image]

**EDIT 2:** As azerbajdzan points out, the order of the data can affect the results. Sorting the data with [`FindCurvePath`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html) avoids this as well as obviating the need for increased precision.

```
dataNLM = PadRight[#, 3, 0] & /@ data[[FindCurvePath[data][[1]]]];

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   dataNLM, {a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f, b^2 - 4*a*c == 0}, 
   {a, b, c, d, e, f}, {x, y}];

fit = nlm["BestFit"]

(* -0.0630982 - 0.139883 x + 0.017491 x^2 - 0.136823 y - 0.0251865 x y + 
 0.00832389 y^2 *)

ContourPlot[Evaluate[fit == 0], {x, -5, 70}, {y, -8, 100}, 
 Prolog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, Point@data}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 NIce! So what changed - only `WorkingPrecision -> 15`?

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov - Also, the model was altered and a constraint was added.

Comment: @cvgmt - I used the model from [`wiki`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#In_a_Cartesian_coordinate_system)

Comment: @BobHanlon Nice solution, but you don't fullfill the restriction "fit a parabola"!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann There are a constraint `b^2 - 4*a*c == 0` in the code to `fit a parabola`

Comment: @cvgmt Didn't see it, thanks for your hint

Comment: @BobHanlon Clever solution! The coefficients `a,b,c,d,e,f` are only unique except for one common factor. That's why I tried  `nlm = NonlinearModelFit[dataNLM,
   {a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f,
    b^2 - 4*a*c == 0,f==1}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, {x, y},
   WorkingPrecision -> 15];` with an additional constraint `f==1`. To my surprise the result is much worse. Any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann - see edit for `f==1`

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks for your edit. But my question concerns direct evaluation of `NonlinearModelFit` with the additional constraint `f==1`

Comment: I do not understand why `data` had to be pad with `0` as third coordinate? We have two coordinates in data and two variables `x,y` and when we pad data we have three coordinates and two variables. Yet Mathematica outputs error with unpadded data as "number of coordinates is 1 and number of variables is 2" which is nonsense.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Does not always work, see my answer.

Comment: @azerbajdzan - Sort the data with [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html), i.e., `dataNLM = PadRight[#, 3, 0] & /@ ndata[[FindCurvePath[ndata][[1]]]];`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: First Point:  {b^2, 4 a c} /. nlm["BestFitParameters"] -->
(* {0.0005165, 0.0004772} *).  So your fit is close to a parabola, but actually a hyperbola. It seems NonlinearModelFit doesn't strictly enforce the constraint.

Comment: @azerbajdan: Due to a  bug  First[FindCurvePath@dataFindCurvePath] does not include {10, 7, 6, 1} as it should. After correcting for the bug in FindCurvePath I see that changing the order of the points doesn't change the fit.

Answer (score 7):

Just a variant:(as per comment: this fits conic not parabola. In this case hyperbola).

Using:

```
data = {{15.4, 59.1}, {12.8, 52.6}, {5.8, 34.9}, {8.1, 41.2}, {9.7, 
    45.0}, {17.1, 62.8}, {25.7, 82.5}, {9.9, 46.0}, {6.4, 
    36.9}, {29.1, 89.8}, {60.0, 42.0}, {35.8, 19.9}, {27.0, 
    12.4}, {0.5, -0.8}, {43.8, 27.0}, {25.7, 11.5}, {23.6, 
    9.7}, {62.9, 44.7}, {41.6, 25.0}, {14.0, 3.03}, {-1.6, 
    5.3}, {-1.4, 10.2}};
```

You can use [`LinearModelFit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearModelFit.html):

```
td = {#1^2, #1 #2, #1, #2, #2^2} & @@@ data;
f = LinearModelFit[td, {1, x2, xy, x, y}, {x2, xy, x, y}]
par[x_, y_] := y^2 - f["BestFitParameters"] . {1, x^2, x y, x, y}
ContourPlot[par[x, y] == 0, {x, -10, 100}, {y, -10, 100}, 
 Epilog -> Point[data], PlotLabel -> par[x, y] == 0]
```

[image]

Comment: You gave a very nice way to find the conic-section that best fits the data and that is another problem I am interested in. The task was to find the parabola with a best fit, and a parabola is a specific type of conic-section.

Comment: Yes you are right I fit a conic not a parabola (as is evident from equation). Just time poor and used a general approach. If time permits will look at parabola.

Answer (score 4):

- @Bob Hanlon have provided an excellent answer. Here we try to variant the setting to get some best fit and remove `Rationalize` and `WorkingPrecision->15`.
- Since it is not easy to satisfy the condition `b^2 - 4 a*c==0`, we try to deduce a weak condition,that is if `b^2==4 a*c`,then `a*c>=0` and for any positive number `δ>0`, `-δ<b^2 - 4 a*c<δ`,so we  relax the restriction `b^2 - 4 a*c==0` to

```
 -10^-10 < b^2 - 4 a*c < 10^-10, a*c> 0
```

```
Clear["Global`*"]; 
data = {{15.4, 59.1}, {12.8, 52.6}, {5.8, 
   34.9}, {8.1, 41.2}, {9.7, 45.0}, {17.1, 62.8}, {25.7, 82.5}, {9.9, 
   46.0}, {6.4, 36.9}, {29.1, 89.8}, {60.0, 42.0}, {35.8, 
   19.9}, {27.0, 12.4}, {0.5, -0.8}, {43.8, 27.0}, {25.7, 
   11.5}, {23.6, 9.7}, {62.9, 44.7}, {41.6, 25.0}, {14.0, 
   3.03}, {-1.6, 5.3}, {-1.4, 10.2}};
dataNLM = PadRight[#, 3, 0] & /@ data;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   dataNLM, {a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f, -10^-10 < 
     b^2 - 4 a*c < 10^-10, a*c > 0}, {a, c, d, e, b, f}, {x, y}];
fit = nlm["BestFit"];
para = nlm["BestFitParameters"];
b^2 - 4 a*c /. para
ContourPlot[fit == 0, {x, -5, 70}, {y, -8, 100}, 
 Prolog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, Point@data}]
```

[image]

- If we want to use `ellipse` to approximate the `parabola`, we can use

```
b^2 - 4 a*c < -10^-8, a*c >= 0
```

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   dataNLM, {a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f, 
    b^2 - 4 a*c < -10^-8, a*c >= 0}, {a, c, d, e, b, f}, {x, y}];
fit = nlm["BestFit"];
para = nlm["BestFitParameters"];
b^2 - 4 a*c /. para
ContourPlot[fit == 0, {x, -2000, 2000}, {y, -2000, 2000}, 
 Prolog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, Point@data}]
```

[image]

- If we want to use `hyperbola` to approximate the `parabola`, we can use

```
0<= b^2 - 4 a*c <10^-8, a*c >= 0
```

```
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   dataNLM, {a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f, 
    0 <= b^2 - 4 a*c < 10^-8, a*c >= 0}, {a, c, d, e, b, f}, {x, y}];
fit = nlm["BestFit"];
para = nlm["BestFitParameters"];
b^2 - 4 a*c /. para
ContourPlot[fit == 0, {x, -2000, 2000}, {y, -2000, 2000}, 
 Prolog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, Point@data}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does not always work, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here I'll try to fullfill the restriction **fit parabola**.

In my approach I'll try to minimize the normal distance of data-points an the parabola. Thereby first the problem is expanded with some additional points `{u,v}` defined in `var`

```
n = Length[data] 
var = Table[{u[i], v[i]}, {i, 1, n}];
```

In the definition of `J` we try to minimize two parts, the definition of the conic part and the distance `Norm[{x,y},{u,v}]`

```
penalty=10;    
J = Total@
MapThread[ (a*#2[[1]]^2 + b*#2[[1]]*#2[[2]] + c*#2[[2]]^2 +d*#2[[1]] + e*#2[[2]] + f)^2 + 
penalty (#1 - #2) . (#1 - #2) &, {data, var}];
minJ = NMinimize[ {J, b^2 == 4 a c}, 
Join[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, Flatten[var]]];
Show[{ContourPlot[ (a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f  /.minJ[[2]] ) == 0, {x, -10, 100}, {y, -10, 100}], ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The code work in v12.3 but not in v13.3.1.  I don't know why. In v12.3, `b^2 == 4 a c /. minJ[[2]]` also `False`.

Comment: @cvgmt But `b^2-4a c/.minJ[[2]]` is numerical small

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Does not work with all possible permutations of `data` - see my answer.

Comment: Very instructive: +1 of course

Answer (score 3):

This not an answer but just comparison of answers posted by other authors.

Neither @Bob Hanlon's method nor @cvgmt's method seems to work in all circumstances. (I forgot - but also @Ulrich Neumann method does not work with `ndata`)

The method should work for all `RandomSample` of `data`.

In contrast @ubpdqn method seems to works for all permutaions of `data`.

@Bob Hanlon

```
data = {{15.4, 59.1}, {12.8, 52.6}, {5.8, 34.9}, {8.1, 41.2}, {9.7, 
     45.0}, {17.1, 62.8}, {25.7, 82.5}, {9.9, 46.0}, {6.4, 
     36.9}, {29.1, 89.8}, {60.0, 42.0}, {35.8, 19.9}, {27.0, 
     12.4}, {0.5, -0.8}, {43.8, 27.0}, {25.7, 11.5}, {23.6, 
     9.7}, {62.9, 44.7}, {41.6, 25.0}, {14.0, 3.03}, {-1.6, 
     5.3}, {-1.4, 10.2}} // Rationalize;
ndata = {{43.8`, 27.`}, {5.8`, 34.9`}, {25.7`, 11.5`}, {14.`, 
     3.03`}, {35.8`, 19.9`}, {60.`, 42.`}, {17.1`, 62.8`}, {41.6`, 
     25.`}, {9.9`, 46.`}, {15.4`, 59.1`}, {-1.6`, 
     5.3`}, {0.5`, -0.8`}, {62.9`, 44.7`}, {25.7`, 82.5`}, {12.8`, 
     52.6`}, {9.7`, 45.`}, {-1.4`, 10.2`}, {6.4`, 36.9`}, {29.1`, 
     89.8`}, {23.6`, 9.7`}, {8.1`, 41.2`}, {27.`, 12.4`}} // 
   Rationalize;
dataNLM = PadRight[#, 3, 0] & /@ ndata;

Sort[data] == Sort[ndata]

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   dataNLM, {a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f, 
    b^2 - 4*a*c == 0}, {a, b, c, d, e, f}, {x, y}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 15];

fit = nlm["BestFit"]

ContourPlot[Evaluate[fit == 0], {x, -5, 70}, {y, -8, 100}, 
 Prolog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, Point@ndata}]

(* True *)
(* 0.885290205634689 - 0.173557536673257 x + 0.0153601256491121 x^2 -
```

0.159274924329589 y - 0.0205406553450794 x y +
0.00743160825351122 y^2 *)

[image]

@cvgmt

```
data = RandomSample[{{15.4, 59.1}, {12.8, 52.6}, {5.8, 34.9}, {8.1, 
     41.2}, {9.7, 45.0}, {17.1, 62.8}, {25.7, 82.5}, {9.9, 
     46.0}, {6.4, 36.9}, {29.1, 89.8}, {60.0, 42.0}, {35.8, 
     19.9}, {27.0, 12.4}, {0.5, -0.8}, {43.8, 27.0}, {25.7, 
     11.5}, {23.6, 9.7}, {62.9, 44.7}, {41.6, 25.0}, {14.0, 
     3.03}, {-1.6, 5.3}, {-1.4, 10.2}}];
ndata = {{43.8`, 27.`}, {5.8`, 34.9`}, {25.7`, 11.5`}, {14.`, 
    3.03`}, {35.8`, 19.9`}, {60.`, 42.`}, {17.1`, 62.8`}, {41.6`, 
    25.`}, {9.9`, 46.`}, {15.4`, 59.1`}, {-1.6`, 
    5.3`}, {0.5`, -0.8`}, {62.9`, 44.7`}, {25.7`, 82.5`}, {12.8`, 
    52.6`}, {9.7`, 45.`}, {-1.4`, 10.2`}, {6.4`, 36.9`}, {29.1`, 
    89.8`}, {23.6`, 9.7`}, {8.1`, 41.2`}, {27.`, 12.4`}};

Sort[data] == Sort[ndata]

dataNLM = PadRight[#, 3, 0] & /@ ndata;
nlm = NonlinearModelFit[
   dataNLM, {a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f, -10^-10 < 
     b^2 - 4 a*c < 10^-10, a > 0}, {a, c, d, e, b, f}, {x, y}];
fit = nlm["BestFit"];
para = nlm["BestFitParameters"];
b^2 - 4 a*c /. para
ContourPlot[fit == 0, {x, -5, 70}, {y, -8, 100}, 
 Prolog -> {AbsolutePointSize@5, Red, Point@ndata}]

(* True *)
(* 5.19522*10^-6 *)
```

[image]

@ubpdqn

```
data = RandomSample[{{15.4, 59.1}, {12.8, 52.6}, {5.8, 34.9}, {8.1, 
     41.2}, {9.7, 45.0}, {17.1, 62.8}, {25.7, 82.5}, {9.9, 
     46.0}, {6.4, 36.9}, {29.1, 89.8}, {60.0, 42.0}, {35.8, 
     19.9}, {27.0, 12.4}, {0.5, -0.8}, {43.8, 27.0}, {25.7, 
     11.5}, {23.6, 9.7}, {62.9, 44.7}, {41.6, 25.0}, {14.0, 
     3.03}, {-1.6, 5.3}, {-1.4, 10.2}}];
ndata = {{43.8`, 27.`}, {5.8`, 34.9`}, {25.7`, 11.5`}, {14.`, 
    3.03`}, {35.8`, 19.9`}, {60.`, 42.`}, {17.1`, 62.8`}, {41.6`, 
    25.`}, {9.9`, 46.`}, {15.4`, 59.1`}, {-1.6`, 
    5.3`}, {0.5`, -0.8`}, {62.9`, 44.7`}, {25.7`, 82.5`}, {12.8`, 
    52.6`}, {9.7`, 45.`}, {-1.4`, 10.2`}, {6.4`, 36.9`}, {29.1`, 
    89.8`}, {23.6`, 9.7`}, {8.1`, 41.2`}, {27.`, 12.4`}};

Sort[data] == Sort[ndata]

td = {#1^2, #1 #2, #1, #2, #2^2} & @@@ ndata;
f = LinearModelFit[td, {1, x2, xy, x, y}, {x2, xy, x, y}]
par[x_, y_] := y^2 - f["BestFitParameters"] . {1, x^2, x y, x, y}
ContourPlot[par[x, y] == 0, {x, -10, 100}, {y, -10, 100}, 
 Epilog -> Point[ndata], PlotLabel -> par[x, y] == 0]
Clear[f]

(* True *)
(* FittedModel[5.03791 +16.6109 x-2.08349 x2+3.00068 xy+16.7359 y] *)
```

[image]

**Updated with @Ulrich Neumann code:**

```
data = {{12.8, 52.6}, {25.7, 82.5}, {17.1, 62.8}, {60., 42.}, {5.8, 
    34.9}, {27., 12.4}, {9.7, 45.}, {43.8, 27.}, {25.7, 11.5}, {14., 
    3.03}, {15.4, 59.1}, {62.9, 44.7}, {23.6, 9.7}, {6.4, 36.9}, {9.9,
     46.}, {8.1, 41.2}, {41.6, 25.}, {-1.6, 5.3}, {35.8, 
    19.9}, {0.5, -0.8}, {29.1, 89.8}, {-1.4, 10.2}};
n = Length[data];
var = Table[{u[i], v[i]}, {i, 1, n}];
penalty = 10;
J = Total@
   MapThread[(a*#2[[1]]^2 + b*#2[[1]]*#2[[2]] + c*#2[[2]]^2 + 
         d*#2[[1]] + e*#2[[2]] + f)^2 + 
      penalty (#1 - #2) . (#1 - #2) &, {data, var}];
minJ = NMinimize[{J, b^2 == 4 a c}, 
   Join[{a, b, c, d, e, f}, Flatten[var]]];
Show[{ContourPlot[(a*x^2 + b*x*y + c*y^2 + d*x + e*y + f /. 
      minJ[[2]]) == 0, {x, -10, 100}, {y, -10, 100}], ListPlot[data]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not that simple, try with removed `a>0` and `ndata={{0.5, -0.8}, {15.4, 59.1}, {43.8, 27.}, {14., 3.03}, {5.8, 
  34.9}, {25.7, 11.5}, {60., 42.}, {23.6, 9.7}, {17.1, 62.8}, {12.8, 
  52.6}, {29.1, 89.8}, {9.7, 45.}, {25.7, 82.5}, {9.9, 46.}, {35.8, 
  19.9}, {62.9, 44.7}, {-1.4, 10.2}, {-1.6, 5.3}, {27., 12.4}, {41.6, 
  25.}, {6.4, 36.9}, {8.1, 41.2}}`.

Comment: @cvgmt: There is other permutation that will not work with `a<0`. Other with `a>0` and other with completely removed inequation.

Comment: But @ubpdqn's method seems to work in all circumstances, I was not able to find a permutation that would cause failure, but of course I have not tested all the permutations.

Comment: @ubpdqn's method ,the `b^2 - 4 a*c` is equal to `0.670154` seems too large.

Comment: Why you think `b^2 - 4 a*c` should be small?

Comment: When `b^2 - 4 a*c>0`, the curve is a `hyperbola` and when `b^2 - 4 a*c<0`, the curve is a `ellipse`,only when `b^2 - 4 a*c=0` ,the curve is a `parabola`.

Comment: For example, we can use `ContourPlot[par[x, y] == 0, {x, -2000, 2000}, {y, -2000, 2000}, 
 Epilog -> Point[ndata], PlotLabel -> par[x, y] == 0]` to see that the solution of @ubpdqn's is a `hyperbola`.

Comment: The algorithm searches for best fit of conic section. Who am I to doubt when the data resembles more hyperbola then a parabola? But yes, if you and the OP insist it must be a parabola then also @ubpdqn method should be adjusted.

Comment: @cvgmt: Maybe this is why your and Bob Hanlon's method fails for some permutation of the input. Because the algorithm wants to force a hyperbola to be a parabola.

Comment: (+1) Thanks your comment. Now I clarify my approach.

Comment: @azerbajdzan My approach works fine with `ndata`!

Comment: @azerbajdzan: I added an update to the question where I show what I found by manually using Manipulate to look for a true parabola the fits the data as well as I could. The optimal parabola will be slightly better than the one I found manually.

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: Can't you see that the curve does not fit the points of `ndata` at the tip of the parabola properly? Try different permutation that makes it even more evident: `data={{12.8`,52.6`},{25.7`,82.5`},{17.1`,62.8`},{60.`,42.`},{5.8`,34.9`},{27.`,12.4`},{9.7`,45.`},{43.8`,27.`},{25.7`,11.5`},{14.`,3.03`},{15.4`,59.1`},{62.9`,44.7`},{23.6`,9.7`},{6.4`,36.9`},{9.9`,46.`},{8.1`,41.2`},{41.6`,25.`},{-1.6`,5.3`},{35.8`,19.9`},{0.5`,-0.8`},{29.1`,89.8`},{-1.4`,10.2`}}`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan You didn't show your results that's why I couldn't see (your) results. I checked it myself and got optimal parabola for `data` and `ndata`!

Comment: @Ulrich Neumann: I updated my post with your code. Maybe it is version dependent, but on my version 13.0. it does not work for all permutations of `data`.

Comment: @azerbajdzan Thanks for the edit. My version is v12.2 ! In my opinion a result of `NonlinearModelFit` function which depends on the ordering of the data isn't trustable!

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a function `f(u)` that takes an angle as the argument.
2. In `f` first rotate all points by the angle `u`.
3. Next in `f` calculate the sum of squares (SSQ) resulting from a linear regression on the rotated points.
4. Print the coefficients `(a,b,c)` estimated by the linear regression.
5. Return SSQ as the function result.

Now, bracket `u` between -90 and 90 degrees. Use a minimizer on `f(u)` to find the optimal value of `u`. The last coefficients printed out gives you the solution together with `u`.